# Can't set text direction for right-to-left languages

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I'm developing an Office App which translates the content of a Word document. I use *Office.select("bindings#MyBindingWordDoc").setDataAsync()* to set the content after is being translated.

The problem is that for Arabic languages the test direction must be right to left, but I can't find a way to set this property.

Do you know any solution for this issue?

Thank you,
Raul

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution, set the format on a template file for your app to launch at so you do not need to set this programatically. you can set this property in the project properties in VS 2015.

Hope this solution works with you.

Comment: I'm not sure i can use this solution because i have to change the text direction dynamically if the user translate a document from English to Arabic and vise versa. I believe a template will apply to all documents, regardless of the language. Am I right?

Comment: yes. you select if the app would run on a new document every time or use an existing template.